# PHP shell_exec() in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, php, lamp

I am using ubuntu with libreOffice. I have installed `unoconv` for convert a `*.odp` file to `*.pdf`. When i run the command `unoconv -f pdf myfile.odp` from terminal then it works very fine. I want to do the same thing with using PHP `shell_exec()` method. So, I wrote the following code:

```
$output = shell_exec('unoconv -f pdf test.odp 2>&1');
echo $output;
```

But it shows the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python: /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/python) 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 24, in import uno,
unohelper File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.py", line 34, in import pyuno SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apach may be configured to disallow calling some command/libs...

But maybe environment variables (e.g. $PATH...) are not just the same for your user and Apach user (www-data) or something like that.

**Here is an example what you can do to search the issue:**

Try to call `set` or `setenv` to get the list of the variables.

Create a basic script `callset.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set
```

(do not forget `chmod +x callset.sh` to give execution permission):

Then call this `bash` script from PHP:

```
$output = shell_exec ('/your/dir/callset.sh 2>&1');
echo $output
```

or

```
exec ("/your/dir/callset.sh", $output, $exitstatus);
print_r ($output);
```

Then check the difference with your own `set` call.

Finally provide the missing variables like that:

```
$output = shell_exec('PATH=aaa:bbb:ddd unoconv -f pdf test.odp 2>&1');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but still have same problem....

Comment: Hi @Arif. What have you tested? Differences within the environment variables? Have you tried to log on using Apach user (`www-data`) and then to run `unoconv`?